How to remove a PostLayoutPulseListener in JavaFx after a condition is met?
Explaining a problem
I have a JavaFx application, where I am using a PostLayoutPulseListener to repeatedly try to perform a task until it succeeds. Once the task is successful, I want to remove the listener. Here is the code snippet I am using:
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class PulseListenerExample extends Application {

    private boolean initialized = false;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

        scene.addPostLayoutPulseListener(() -> {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(50);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            boolean isInited = forceInit();
            if (isInited) {
                // I tried to remove the listener with the following line:
                scene.addPostLayoutPulseListener(null);
            }
        });

        primaryStage.setTitle("Pulse Listener Example");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private boolean forceInit() {
        try {
            // Do some initialization logic
            return true; // Return true, if successfull.
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false; // Return false, if not successfull.
        }
    }
}


Attempt to resolve

Which can be seen in the example. I tried to remove the listener with this line: scene.addPostLayoutPulseListener(null);, but I get the following exception:java.lang.NullPointerException: Scene pulse listener should not be null


You should be using scene.removePostLayoutPulseListener(...) to remove the listener (which would involve a little refactoring). However, what you are trying to do here doesn't make a whole lot of sense. What kind of initialization do you need to do that relies on the scene having been laid out? This just seems like you are asking to fix the wrong approach to whatever problem you are trying to solve.

You can use an anonymous class instead of a lambda expression. That way you can refer to the listener as this within the class and pass it to removePostLayoutPulseListener. But I agree this seems like an XY Problem. What problem is this listener solving in the first place?

Additionally note you should not sleep on the FX Application thread, as you do here. So even if you fix the immediate problem of removing the listener, you also need to fix that and that will likely entail finding a new approach anyway.

Is this an xyproblem?  If so, follow the "what to do about it?" instructions in the link.
